# Trying to develop a search engine, have error in my code

Tags: php, mysql

I get an error

> Undefined index: value

on the line `$search_value = $_GET['value'];`.

I'm trying to create a basic search engine with PHP and MySQL.

```
mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_database);


 if(isset($_GET['search'])){

        $search_value = $_GET['value'];

        $query = "select * from backedupdata where descr like '%$search_value%'";

        $run = mysql_query($query);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)){

                $hddn = $row['hddno'];
                $dat = $row['date'];
                $cover = $row['coverc'];
                $desc = $row['descr'];

                echo "<h2>Date: $dat</h2><br /><h3>Hdd No: $hddn</h3><br /><h3>Cover Colour: $cover</h3><br /><h3>Description:</h3><p>$desc</p><hr>";

            }

    }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you please show me your form?

Comment: Check that field is set before trying to access it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: <form method="get" action="search.php">
         <input type="text"  name="search"  placeholder="Search for data"><input type="submit" name="search" value="Search Now" >
      
        </form>

Comment: **WARNING:** You're using a deprecated database API and you're open to SQL Injection. `$search_value = foo%' OR 1=1 --`

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
if(isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['value'])){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this error because your page have no field called `value` in `$_GET`

Try to display what your `$_GET[]` contains using this :

```
print_r ($_GET);
```

or

```
var_dump ($_GET);
```

or you can add a test in your `if` clause :

```
if(isset($_GET['search']) && isset($_GET['value'])){
...
```